# Adjust UILabel height by content in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

i have 3 types of string labels, "loading...", "loading, please wait" and "it's taking more than we expected, sorry...". I want to adjust the height of the IULabel and center in the frame. I'm using this:

```
labelTitle = new UILabel (new CGRect (
                frame.Width / 4,
                frame.Height / 2 + Dimensions.margin_small,
                frame.Width/2,
                40
            ));
labelTitle.StyleTitle ();
labelTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
labelTitle.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
labelTitle.Lines = 0;
```

But don't know how to resize the height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
labelTitle = new UILabel ();
labelTitle.StyleTitle ();
labelTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
labelTitle.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
labelTitle.Lines = 0;
```

And now give the label center point.

Comment: that's was the answer, i just needed to make the new CGRect()  after that for every update, and now it works